# Install qt database driver

Tags: 20.04, qt, postgresql

I’m trying to install the QT database driver QPSQL int Ubuntu 20.04 system. but I honestly have no club how to do that.
Is there a way to do that by using Apt, or
Should I delete all Qt stuff installed by apt and then install Qt by hand?

What is the best way?

**EDIT**

```
apt install libqt5sql5-psql
```

Solved it.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the `libqt5sql5-psql` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt install libqt5sql5-psql`

solved it